# Local node process running in wrong directory

Tags: node.js

I am using PHP storm 9 to run a node instance on my local dev environment., but the process seems to be running in server.js parent directory.

My folder structure looks like

```
app/
  app_server/
    server.js
    user_resources/
  user_resources/
```

When i write a file with in my local instance to writes user_resources in app/ and when i run the same process on live environment it writes to user_resources in app_server/

```
pdf.create(html, options).toFile(path+filename, function (err, reuslt) {
  callback();
});
```

using fs writeFile, readFile or readdir gives similar behavior

Local node server i ran with PHPstorm and live server runs with forever

Both local and live is a ubuntu system.

Any suggestings to why local node seems to be running in server.js parent directory.

Comment: Are you sure the process is started from the same directory on both production and locally? Asking because `cd app/app_server; node server.js` and `cd app; node app_server/server.js` make a huge difference.

Comment: Not user locally i run it though phpstorm debugger by starting it directly in phpstorm. live i use cd app/app_server; forever start server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node server is probably executed from the `app` directory by PHPStorm, while the live process runs from `app/app_server`.

If no other hint is provided in the server code on where exactly to put the `user_resources` it will reside within the current working directory (which is the path from where the node process was involved).

You may want to specify a path relative to the location of the `server.js`, this can easily be done like this:

```
var userResourcePath = __dirname + '/user_resources`;
```

Node always ensures the `__dirname` to be set to the path of the file it is in.

I made the assumption the `user_resources` path of your live environment (`app/app_server/user_resources`) is the one you want for local development.